# FCM - Setting badge in onMessageReceived

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have an Android application, where I'm using some method to show notification number on app icon. Now I want to set that number when notification is received.

I thought that I should set the number when notification received so I set it inside `onMessageReceived` method. But, my problem is **when my app is in background, `onMessageReceived` method not called, so the notification number isn't set.**

Following is my code. I set the number inside `onMessageReceived`. I already tested `setBadge` method and can verify that it is working. The problem is `onMessageReceived` is not called so `setBadge` is also not called, which doesn't set the number.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Conts.notificationCounter ++;
    //I am setting in here.
    setBadge(getApplicationContext(),Conts.notificationCounter  );
    Log.e("notificationNUmber",":"+ Conts.notificationCounter);

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]



public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
    String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
    if (launcherClassName == null) {
        Log.e("classname","null");
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
        String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
            String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            return className;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I searched this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/37845174), I found that if the coming message is *display message* then `onMessageReceived` is called only if app is foreground. But if coming message is *data message* then `onMessageReceived` is called even if the app is background.

But my friend told me who is sending the notification(server side), the message already goes as both display and data message. He said that data object is filled.

Following is the **JSON** for **coming message**, it has **data object**.

```
{  
   "to":"my_device_id",
   "priority":"high",

   "notification":{  
      "body":"Notification Body",
      "title":"Notification Title",
      "icon":"myicon",
      "sound":"default"
   },

   "data":{  
      "Nick":"DataNick",
      "Room":"DataRoom"
   }
}
```

If I only use data object, onMessageReceived is called as they said but that time notification does not appear at the top.

Now why `onMessageReceived` is not called if the message is also data message. Should I do something different to handle data message? Is it working same with display messaging in client side.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way to call *onMessageReceived* unless the coming json includes **ONLY data payload** as I learned from Firebase support.

So I have to use data payload but if you use data payload it **does not show notification** at the top so you should create your custom notification using data payload information.

So I **sent notification to myself** when I get the data payload **in onMessageReceived**. And I set the badge in onMessageReceived right after sending notification to myself.

Following code is the final version.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //for data payload
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"), title);
        badge = Integer.parseInt(remoteMessage.getData().get("badge"));
        Log.e("notificationNUmber",":"+badge);
        setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badge);

    }
    //for notification payload so I did not use here
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String title) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notify_no /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    if (notify_no < 9) {
        notify_no = notify_no + 1;
    } else {
        notify_no = 0;
    }
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_3_web)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(notify_no + 2 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: **setBadge default method?**

> setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badge);

Comment: No,it is not. I used some github codes. Setbadge  is part of that.

Comment: Could you provide the link to the Github code you have used

Comment: Okay sorry for my previous comment. I think I was confused about setBadge method, because I am trying to find which library for hours and could not find any related library. That seems those codes under setBadge can work without any library but I guess only for Samsung devices=> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261795/5528870  People say this library is nice and works numerous devices=> https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger Also I learned that since api level 26 there is a default method for setting badges. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#java @Pratik

Answer (score 3):

To do stuff when receiving Notification-payloads in the background, just override zzE in FirebaseMessagingService. The method name might change between versions, just type @Override into the class and see what it suggests for you. In my case, I found zzD and zzE, and by trying them out I noticed that zzE has the data I wanted. zzD had some wakelock-stuff in its extras. The return value of zzE basically indicates whether the notification was handled, so if you return true, the OS won't show the notification. I prefer to return super.zzE(intent) after I've done my things, to let the OS handle the notification.

Updating the badge will only work on launchers supported by ShortcutBadger though. You can do pretty much whatever you want instead, though.

Here's my code (my notifications contain "badge" in the data payload):

```
public class PushNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        // This is called when the app is in the foreground
        // Show a custom notification or send a broadcast to update the UI here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zzE(Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.hasExtra("badge"))
        {
            try
            {
                ShortcutBadger.applyCount(getApplicationContext(), Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("badge"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("failedToParse", "Badge!?");
            }
        }
        // pass the intent through to the non-overriden zzE 
        // to show the default notification. 
        return super.zzE(intent);

        // You could also show a custom notification here
        // and return true instead of this if you 
        // don't want the default notifications.
    }

}
```

Comment: Not able to find zzE()

Comment: This works with firebase 10.2.1, in later versions that method has been hidden. That old version still works nicely though, so I'm sticking with it until a different solution comes up. I really don't understand why they would hide that though, I don't see what harm it would do to allow developers to override how notifications are shown...