# Firebase notifications badge android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase notifications. This is FirebaseMessagingService:

```
class mFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private lateinit var notification: Notification
    private val badgeCount = 3 //value to show in badge

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.notification.body)
    }

    private fun sendNotification(message: String) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.resources, R.drawable.img))
                .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

        notification = builder.build()

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification)
        ShortcutBadger.applyNotification(applicationContext, notification, badgeCount) //trying to use it
    }
}
```

I need to set icon badge count to my value, but Firebase set it to count of notifications. I'm trying to use [ShortcutBadger library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) but it doesn't work well with firebase notifications. Works only if notifications creating programmatically (by the button for example). Any idea?

Comment: Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39326508/fcm-setting-badge-in-onmessagereceived), looks pretty similar to what you're looking for!